# Refactor really complicated method (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, refactoring

I made a Spring service as follows :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public void reallyComplicatedMethod(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f){
        // over 9000 lines of code that use anotherService
    }
}
```

The code looks brief but it contains a lot of nested "if" "else" everywhere

So I refactor it to separate different parts :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public void reallyComplicatedMethod(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f){
        part1(a, b, c);
        part2(a, b, c, d, e, f);
        part3(a);
        // ...
    }

    private void part1(A a, B b, C c){...}
    private void part2(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f){
        // imagine a lot of if else for ...
        part2_1(a, b, c);
        part2_2(d, e, f);
    }
    private void part2_1(A a, B b, C c){...}
    private void part2_2(D d, E e, F f){...}

    private void part3(A a){...}
    // other parts

}
```

I have a lot more arguments (A, B, C, D ...), with complicate names that are really invasive in my "partX" methods.

So I add it into an object that contains all those arguments. I use this object to launch the process instead of passing it in every method.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public void reallyComplicatedMethod(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f){
        new DoMyMethod(a, b, c, d, e, f).run();
    }

    class DoMyMethod {
        A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f;

        // It can also be a Builder (if there are too many parameters)
        DoMyMethod(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f){
            // el famoso constructor with this.x = x;
        }

        void run() {
            part1();
            part2();
            part3();
            // ...
        }

        private void part1(){...}
        private void part2(){...}
        // sub part2
        private void part3(){...}
        // other parts
    }
}
```

At the end, I find the "partX" method really cool to read but the architecture feels like "wtf are you doing bruh ?!"

Adding other classes that do the job is a convenient way to do this, but Spring @Autowired services and arguments have to be changed everywhere.

Can you please give me some advice? like some kind of design pattern for example :)

Comment: i personally think this is more a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question

Answer (score 2):

Although it's hard to say exactly how you can improve this code, there are a few things you can take into consideration. Generally speaking, if a method is taking so many parameters, you can probably break it up into smaller methods. It's quite possible that your method is doing too many things. Also, it seems you are treating your `DoMyMethod` object as a function rather than an object. Even though this is fine in some cases, it adds extra layers of abstraction that will probably make your code harder to maintain.

My advice is to try break the code up into smaller parts, with each function having only 1 or 2 things to do.